# JQuery in the form

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a page https://www.sealskincovers.com/CarLanding/carcovers.php?make=BMW. It has an arrow image just adjacent to the search form. That arrow should come in front of Year field when the page loads. Then the image should move in front of model field when year is selected and so on...

Below javascript/jquery code is used right now on the page:

```
function getmodel() {    
    var sval1 = jQuery('#finder-12--43').val();
    var form_data1 = {
        dropdown_id: '44',
        parent_id: sval1
    };
    var option = document.createElement('option');
    option.value = 0;
    option.text = 'Loading....';
    option.label = 'Loading....';
    jQuery('#finder-12--45').append(option);
    var makeval = '<?php echo $_REQUEST['
    make ']; ?>';

    jQuery('#finder-12--44').html('');
    jQuery.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'https://www.sealskincovers.com/CarLanding/data.php',
        data: form_data1,
        crossDomain: true,
        success: function (response) {
            var object = jQuery.parseJSON(response);
            //alert(object.length);
            jQuery.each(object, function (i, data) {

                if (data.label == makeval) {

                    jQuery('#finder-12--44').append('<option value="' + data.value + '" label="' + data.label + '" selected >' + data.label + '</option>');
                } else {
                    jQuery('#finder-12--44').append('<option value="' + data.value + '" label="' + data.label + '" >' + data.label + '</option>');
                }
            });
            var sval = jQuery('#finder-12--44').val();

            var form_data = {
                dropdown_id: '45',
                parent_id: sval
            };
            jQuery.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'https://www.sealskincovers.com/CarLanding/data.php',
                data: form_data,
                crossDomain: true,
                success: function (response) {

                    var object = jQuery.parseJSON(response);
                    var rlen = object.length;
                    if (rlen > 0) {
                        if (!jQuery('#finder-12--45').is('disabled')) {
                            jQuery('#finder-12--45').removeAttr('disabled');
                        }
                        jQuery('#finder-12--45').html('');
                        jQuery('#finder-12--46').html('');
                        jQuery('#finder-12--46').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
                        jQuery.each(object, function (i, data) {


                            jQuery('#finder-12--45').append('<option value="' + data.value + '" label="' + data.label + '">' + data.label + '</option>');
                        });
                        jQuery('#finder-12--45').attr('selectedIndex', 0);
                        // alert(jQuery('#finder-12--43').position().top);
                        jQuery(".search_pointer").css({
                            top: jQuery('#finder-12--43').position().top
                        })
                        if (jQuery('#finder-12--43').parent().next().find("button").length > 0) {
                            jQuery(".pointer_text").text("Click Here")
                        } else {
                            jQuery(".pointer_text").text("Select Model")
                        }
                    } else {
                        jQuery('#finder-12--45').html('');
                        jQuery('#finder-12--46').html('');
                        jQuery(".search_pointer").css({
                            top: jQuery('#finder-12--44').position().top
                        })
                        if (jQuery('#finder-12--44').parent().next().find("button").length > 0) {
                            jQuery(".pointer_text").text("Click Here")
                        } else {
                            jQuery(".pointer_text").text("Select Here")
                        }
                    }
                },
            });
        },
    });
}

function getbody() {

    var sval = jQuery('#finder-12--45').val();
    var form_data = {
        dropdown_id: '46',
        parent_id: sval
    };
    var option = document.createElement('option');
    option.value = 0;
    option.text = 'Loading....';
    option.label = 'Loading....';
    jQuery('#finder-12--46').append(option);
    jQuery.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'https://www.sealskincovers.com/CarLanding/data.php',
        data: form_data,
        crossDomain: true,
        success: function (response) {
            var object = jQuery.parseJSON(response);
            jQuery('#finder-12--46').removeAttr('disabled');
            jQuery('#finder-12--46').html('');
            jQuery.each(object, function (i, data) {
                jQuery('#finder-12--46').append('<option value="' + data.value + '" label="' + data.label + '" ' + data.selected + '>' + data.label + '</option>');
            });
            jQuery('#finder-12--46').attr('selectedIndex', 0);
            //alert(jQuery('#finder-12--45').position().top);
            jQuery(".search_pointer").css({
                top: jQuery('#finder-12--45').position().top
            })
            if (jQuery('#finder-12--45').parent().next().find("button").length > 0) {
                jQuery(".pointer_text").text("Click Here")
            } else {
                jQuery(".pointer_text").text("Select " + jQuery('#finder-12--45').parent().next().text())
            }
        },
    });
}

function getview() {
    jQuery(".search_pointer").css({
        top: jQuery('#finder-12--46').position().top
    })
    if (jQuery('#finder-12--46').parent().next().find("button").length > 0) {
        jQuery(".pointer_text").text("Click Here")
    } else {
        jQuery(".pointer_text").text("Select " + jQuery('#finder-12--46').parent().next().text())
    }
}
```

Comment: Please take the time to format your code correctly. It makes it easier for you and others to read, and far more likely for you to get an answer.

Comment: I just looked at the page and it seams that when year is not completed it points to the model and after you complete the year it points to the year (goes one position up). When I use developer tools and change the  search_pointer properties to margin-top:-150 px; the image is shown correctly. So change this css property acording to the form you want to point to. -150px for year -25px for model and 0px for body. I know is just a quick fix and it may not work for other screen resolutions so try with x% instead of xpx....

Answer (score 0):

Try using $('select[name="finder[43]"]') instead of jQuery('#finder-12--43'). I have found success with that method when the class selector doesn't work

and since finding the element is not your problem, it appears that jQuery(".search_pointer") and jQuery('#finder-12--44') are not of the same parent, hence there position reference frames will be different and equating the position.top for the two will probably not give the desired results. you may need make them belong to the same parent element and then do some css position math.